# ¿Cómo Alinear Text debajo de Icon en un QPushButton?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Quiero Realizar Un Boton con el Icono en la parte spuerior y el texto en la parte inferior como se muestra en la imagen: Icono y Texto

el codigo que tengo es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
self.ToolBar = QToolBar()
self.ToolBar.setWindowTitle("Main")
self.ToolBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
self.layoutPrincipal.addWidget(self.ToolBar)



self.Panel1 = QPushButton("Manometer Datasehet")
self.Panel1.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("./Images/manometer.png"))
self.Panel1.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32,32))
self.Panel1.setMinimumSize(90,120)
self.Panel1.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
self.Panel1.setMaximumWidth(250)
self.Panel1.clicked.connect(lambda :
                            self.Manometro.setHidden(False))
self.Panel1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Tahoma", 10))
self.ToolBar.addWidget(self.Panel1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos formas que puedes lograr esto una con css y la otra mas sencilla es usando QToolButton en vez de QPushButton. Tienen casi la mismas propiedades:

```
self.button = QToolButton(self)
                              # importar la clase Qt
self.button.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
```